# Can "albeit" ever be followed by a complete sentence

Tags: conjunctions

"Albeit" can be followed by adverbs, adjectives, and nouns that are used in a adjectival manner:

> The journey was fun, albeit short

> I decided to change my major, albeit reluctantly

> It was a fun journey, albeit a protracted one

> She accepted the offer, albeit with hesitation

Can "albeit" ever be followed by a full sentence, effectively making it synonymous to "though"? For example

> ?The dish was lacking spices, albeit the lack of salt annoyed him much more.

I have seen such usages in the wild, but they strike me as incorrect.

Comment: 'albeit' has no place in the example sentence: you've shifted from spice to seasoning in general. "The dish was lacking spices, **although** the lack of salt annoyed him much more."

Comment: Merriam-Webster has the example "customers seemed generally cheery, albeit some were more cautious than others …"—Cynthia Clark, Publishers Weekly, 26 Jan. 1998

Answer (score 10):

[Eoghan Ryan, at Scribbr {2022)](https://www.scribbr.co.uk/definition/albeit-meaning/#:%7E:text=Albeit%20is%20a%20conjunction%20meaning,main%20clause%20of%20a%20sentence.) essentially proscribes the usage you ask about:

> Albeit is a conjunction meaning ‘even though’ or ‘although’....
>
> It is used to introduce a subordinate clause that qualifies or
> contrasts with the information given in the main clause of a sentence.
>
> Examples: ‘Albeit’ in a sentence
>
> - Ted found the motivational speaker inspiring, albeit a little preachy.
> - Karla is very nice, albeit sometimes stubborn.
> - My car is dependable, albeit old.
> - Sebastian is an artist, albeit an unpopular one.

Correspondingly, none of [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/albeit)'s twenty-odd examples and none of [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/albeit)'s twelve or so are of the form.

But [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/albeit) sees fit to cite a sentence where 'albeit' ***is*** followed by an independent clause:

> Examples of albeit in a Sentence  ...
>
> - … customers seemed generally cheery, albeit some were more cautious than others … —Cynthia Clark, Publishers Weekly, 26 Jan. 1998

(It has the definition

> even though; although,

but fails to comment on the different usages of [even] though:

- He was tall though thin.
- He was tall, though he  was very supple.                   )

I'd say this is a very niche usage (*albeit* is fairly rare in any case). I'd avoid it, in line with the guidance in [Wiktionary's usage note](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/albeit):

> The word *albeit* historically also introduced an independent clause
> as *although* does (as in ... Shakespeare ...); however after the
> Early Modern English period, it ceased to do so, and today only
> introduces a noun phrase, adjectival phrase, adverbial phrase, or
> dependent clause.

Answer (score 7):

> Can "albeit" ever be followed by a full sentence?

Yes

The journey was fun, albeit **it was a short one**

I decided to change my major, albeit **the decision was made** reluctantly

It was a fun journey, albeit **it was** a protracted one. - This is the same as the first, isn't it?

She accepted the offer, albeit **that acceptance came with** with hesitation.

And from published sources:

> 1948 We know them all affectionately as ‘gums’, albeit the botanists
> admit the name only to those species whose bark..is smooth to the
> base. *B. Cronin, How runs Road 68*
>
> 2004 ‘Bridges’ is a..delight..albeit one has to be ready for the
> jazzified force of drummer and percussionist Jamey Haddad.
> *JazzTimes April 115/1*